# jquery extension return $.each confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a jQuery extension I came across ([handsontable](http://handsontable.com/)). I am having no problem creating the table

```
var spreadsheet = $("#dataTable").handsontable({
            rows: 3,
            cols: 15,
            minSpareRows: 2
});
```

However after I create the table I want to call various helper functions I see declared in the javascript for the `Handsontable` object. The problem is the extension seems to return `this.each(function() { ... });` and I don't understand how I can access the underlaying `Handsontable` object from this. The js for the extension can be found [here](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/blob/master/jquery.handsontable.js) and I put a small demo together on the following link

http://jsfiddle.net/7JTG2/7/

as you can see I would like get the data of one of the cells when I click a button.

Comment: It seems your `spreadsheet` variable doesn't have a `grid` member (undefined).

Comment: I'm going to have to advise against using this function. Just have a look at http://datatables.net/ and don't look back.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I just wanted a simple editable grid and not tons of extra features. This seemed to offer that. Eran I am aware of that, the jsFiddle is what I wanted to do, not what I could do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant code is in the end:

```
$.fn.handsontable = function (action, options) {
    if (typeof action !== 'string') { //init
        options = action;
        return this.each(function () {
            if($(this).data("handsontable")) {
                instance = $(this).data("handsontable");
                ...
            } else {
                   ...
                instance = new Handsontable($(this), currentSettings);
                $(this).data("handsontable", instance);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That means, the code sets the `Handsontable` instances as a data attribute to the elements (and returns the selected set to be chainable). Having one element, you can easily extract it with `instance = $el.data("handsontable")`. If you have a set of elements, you will need to loop over it - e.g. with [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: thank you, I clearly didn't look close enough to the function as I should of. Solved my problem.

Comment: See the solution by jmm, which is way better (use the onChange method)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you could just use the onChange method of the plugin to capture data every time it is entered automatically.  No need for a button.  A simple example to add to your code above.

```
onChange: function(data) {
            $("#data").append(JSON.stringify(data));
          }
```

Comment: I am the author of the plugin and I can confirm that is the right way. Thanks guys for your interest!